# How to recover a gzcompressed string stored in PostgreSQL ByteA using PHP PDO Object?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, gzip, bytea

I have a problem in understanding how PHP handle ByteA with postgreSQL binding.

For logging and archiving purposes I store in a `ByteA` column files that I serve with my PHP/Apache Server. For storing, I compress data using `gzencode()` and then I escape string before storing using `pg_escape_bytea()`:

```
// Compress:
if($compress) {
    $data = gzencode($data, 9);
}
// PostgreSQL ByteA Escaping:
$data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
```

I also have a page that allow user to retrieve previous served files. But I cannot succeed for compressed one, and I don't find why:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

/*
$dbCur = $webConn->prepare("SET bytea_output = 'escape';");
$dbCur->execute();
//print_r($dbCur->errorinfo());
*/

$dbCur = $webConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM logs.webservice WHERE Id=?;");
$dbCur->bindParam(1, $id);    
$dbCur->execute();
//print_r($dbCur->errorinfo());

$row = $dbCur->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = stream_get_contents($row['binarydata']);
$data = pg_unescape_bytea($data);

if($row['gzip']) {
    $data = gzdecode($data);
}

header("Content-type: ".$row['mimetype']."; charset=".$row['charset']);
echo $data;
```

I must use PDO object, all examples that I have found (even on PHP website) are based on dedicated DBMS API. Second, `ByteA` column are returned as resources, then I had to use `stream_getcontents()` to get a string. When I store uncompressed files, I can recover from it easily, what ever I use or not `SET bytea_output = 'escape';` query and/or `pg_unescape_bytea()` function. All combinations allow me to get the file.

When I use compressed data, `pg_unescape_bytea()` dramatically eats up almost all my bytes. Anyway, in all combinations, `gzdecode()` fails to work. It seems, I have missing or wrong characters in my binary string that does not block in plain text mode. Anyway, the thing is not well documented on internet and I am stuck without any clue.

How should I recover a gzcompressed string stored in PostgreSQL ByteA using PHP PDO Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solving the retrieval problem only, assuming the insertion works**

Once the binary contents get into `$data` with the following code:

```
$data = stream_get_contents($row['binarydata']);
```

they are already in the raw binary format as needed, so you must not decode it again with this:

`$data = pg_unescape_bytea($data);`

Just remove that spurious unescaping. The reason why you don't notice the problem when `$data` has only ASCII characters is that  `pg_unescape_bytea` converts these characters to themselves (given `bytea_output` is set to escape).

But when the binary stream really contains the full range of 256 possible bytes, such as in gzipped content, then it's guaranteed that `pg_unescape_bytea` will produce a corrupted result in that context.

`pg_unescape_bytea` should only be used on strings that come directly from the database as bytea-encoded-as-text.

**How it's normally done with PDO**

Actually with PDO we're not supposed to use the `pg_[un]escape_bytea` functions, or even any of the functions that start with `pg_*` because PDO is database-independant, and its purpose is to allow for code that works across different databases.

Inserting should be done as described in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php , qualifying the binary parameters with `PDO::PARAM_LOB`. When doing this, PDO will itself encodes the data for a binary transfer, using the appropriate method for the kind of database it's connected to.

When doing explicit escaping with `pg_escape_bytea()`, it produces a string that PDO can consider as a text content and transmit as such. This is a way to transmit binary "behind PDO's back", but there's not much point in doing that.

What definitely does not work is mixing both: escaping (which produces text) **and** telling PDO that it's binary.

Comment: I am really confused about this. I can see that it is linked to charset. But I cannot make it work. I cannot store gzcompressed data into ByteA without using pg_escpae_bytea, and it might be the problem. What I am missing?

Comment: Inserting gzcompressed without pg_escape_bytea gives me ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8b. When I use the fucntion, retreiving data returns something different that I have inserted.

Comment: This page http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=1365 provides a solution, but it is counter productive and is exactly in the opposite way I want to work. I want store binary data (and I cannot do it without alterating the gzip format) instead of hexadecimal stringified representation of binary data.

Comment: I finally found a solution, I edit your question then I can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @jlandercy: I clarified, I hope, in the edit. In your 1st comment it appeared you changed your insertion code but my answer was only about changing the retrieval, not the insert. If you get rid of pg_escape_bytea in the insert, then you must use PDO::PARAM_LOB instead but I think that's what you did eventually.

Comment: Thanks you made it clearer, and now its fully working